# What requirements should I look for in an air compressor to clear irrigation lines?

Tags: irrigation, winterizing

I'm considering purchasing an air compressor to blow out my own sprinklers each winter. (vs paying to have someone else do it) I watched the tech do it last year, and it seemed pretty straightforward. But:

1. What specs (CFM/PSI) are needed to have a suitable compressor for this task?
2. I've never owned a compressor before - what else are they convenient for that I might take into consideration when purchasing one? (I assume they can be used for topping off air pressure in my car tires.)

Comment: Seriously consider getting a "quiet" compressor if you can.  It can be the difference between a pleasant conversation or full on yelling at someone.  Did the tech carry an air compressor to your yard or was it on his truck?

Comment: The need is going to be determined by the layout and extent of your system. Did the guy have an actual plugged-in compressor or just an air bottle? I can't image it's a complex task, though. Other uses - Airing up tires, blowing dust or filth from one place to another, air tools like nailers, sanders, grinders, air hammers, paint guns, sports balls, balloons (if you don't want them to float), etc

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm pretty sure he carried it into the yard. At my old house they ran it from their van.

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom The tour you recommend suggests I can ask about "Which **tools**, materials, and best practices for home improvement task." I'm not asking for product recommendations - I'm asking what tool I need.

Comment: if you're ever going to use it for anything else i would pay attention to the refill rate. Cheap ones are usually slow.  "Quiet" models are still loud AF, so the quicker it shuts up, less you have to listen to it. I find the blower nozzles (under $10) really handy for maintaining electronics, small appliances, and bikes. A $20 18gauge brad nailer is worth every penny. the impact hammers/chisels work really well too.

Comment: You are probably better off with an air bottle that you fill up at whichever gas station does that for free. Buying  a $200+++ compressor for a once-a-year task is a waste of money.

Comment: @Harper Around here it is $100++ for a sprinkler blow out. And, you have to call them, schedule a time when you're home, etc, etc. A $200+ compressor that I can use when it's convenient for me and also for other tasks will pay for itself quickly.

Comment: What does your electrical supply look like?

Comment: @Harper We only have 120V outlets in the garage and outside the house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CFM - cubic feet per minute - is what rushes through the pipes and carries out droplets of water. PSI - pounds per square inch - is what turns ordinary sprinkler heads into high-flying air powered rockets. No kidding.

### How do the big pros do the job??

In my part of the USA the contractors use towable air compressors to sprinkler blow-out. I own two of these and rent them out each fall. Mine are in the 175 CFM class -- they're the type you'd see a road crew using to power a jackhammer for instance. Although these compressors can produce over 100 PSI I prefer to turn it down to about 60 PSI. With a relatively high-flow source like this I can easily blow out a quarter acre residential sprinkler system in 20-30 minutes, including putting the air hoses away.

### OK, I'm not gonna buy nor rent a towable. It's fine if the job takes me longer.

There's a tradeoff between compressor size and job speed. Before I had these compressors I used my electric compressor, an upright unit with a 60 gallon tank and 240 volt motor. I don't recall its CFM spec, but after the tank de-pressurized the compressor pump could move enough air continuously to get the job done at least halfway. I'd go through every sprinkler zone twice to make sure I'd evacuated the water thoroughly. The job took an hour or more.

My brother used to use his portable compressor to do the same. It was big as portables go, maybe 15 gallon tank at the most. Sprinkler blow-out usually took him a couple hours because he'd have to blow off each zone several times and it took several minutes for the air compressor to recover after each shot of air. The biggest difference between his and mine is not actually the size of the pump, though -- it's the size of the air tank. Because my tank stored more air it could push more water further with each cycle. The towables get the job done so fast with no tank at all: their pumps move so much air instantly that a tank isn't needed.

### Can I set the air pressure at max?

People are often set the regulator at a higher pressure. This can help an undersized compressor get the job done by packing more air into the sprinkler main line, acting as if the compressor itself had a larger tank. This does increase the risk of damage to the system however. Valves open with more force, zone piping takes more shock when the valve pops open... and yes, sometimes sprinkler heads really do get launched into the air. Most of the time there's no damage, though, so many people accept that risk.

### Finally, a recommendation!

If the property you're going to winterize is not very big, say under a quarter acre, then there's less volume of pipe to be evacuated. If you don't mind spending half a Saturday doing the job, that's good too. I'd suggest you'll want something with at least an 8-10 gallon tank since that stored air is what gets the job done. 15-30 gallons tank volume would be much nicer. The CFM of the pump just controls how long you'll have to wait before there's enough air to blow it off again.

One thing you can do to expand tank capacity is to get a portable air tank (or a broken compressor). This may be more economical than buying a compressor with a larger tank, especially since it sounds like you may not use it heavily.

Comment: Thanks; this is the type of information I was looking for. The whole property is less than 1/4 acre, and only a portion of that has sprinklers split into 5 zones. I wasn't sure what specs needed to be optimized, but it seems that cfm and tank capacity are what to pay attention to.

Answer (score 1):

Started as a comment but two long.
I have multiple compressors, one is large high volume for use with air tools and spray painting it will pump 18 scfm at 150 psi. That is much bigger than you need.
 I have a portable 5 HP 5 scfm gas powered. Very handy but gas powered is expensive. 
Last I have a “pancake” oil less compressor from harbor freight. This may be 2 scfm at 90 psi but it would probably meet your needs plus fill the tires , and be able to run a small brad nailer. It is light weight , small enough my wife can Cary it around I think it cost about $50 we don’t use it a every day but do regularly use it. it has held up for 8+ years of use.  The tank size is 3 gallons of air on the pancake. 3 gallons of volume will push a lot of water. I looked them up $60 dollars now  but it is 1 scfm at 40 psi and .6 at 90 psi , so it takes a minute to fill the tank max pressure is 100 on current models.  For your needs this inexpensive compressor may be just what you are looking for as far as size and cost. I do have a small portable tank that is 6? Gallons but I fill it from one of my Compressor’s as all the gas stations have pay air fill stations, by the time you buy a tank and get it filled for $1 or more you will find an inexpensive pancake will end up saving time and $ . I think mine came with a cheap hose, tire air chuck and air gun . The hose is light weight but it still works. Other things you should be looking at are pressure gauges and a regulator built in. Some systems have a max pressure of 35 psi so you want to be able to regulate the output pressure or you just may blow the plumbing and or heads apart. Last don’t get one of those 12v models without a tank yes some can pump up to 200 psi but you need volume those tiny ones are less than .1 scfm and are great for bike tires but the one my son purchased melted down before he could get his over sized tire filled.